# What can I do if I'm asked my current salary in New York City or California?

Tags: recruitment, legal

In New York City and California, it is illegal to ask a job candidate his or her current salary. What can I actually *do* if a recruiter asks me my salary?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that's a much better question, since your salary expectations might be very different from your current salary, and while it'd be inappropriate to lie about the current salary, you certainly can name any arbitrary number as your expectations.

Comment: Joe, this should be an answer..

Comment: The existing answers on this come across as a little passive-aggressive and may be counter-productive when you're asked the question by someone you're hoping to work with to find you a position (e.g. a recruiter). I think expanding on Joe's comment above and responding with salary expectations (give them the benefit of the doubt that this is really what they're asking) is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 11):

If someone asks you your salary and you KNOW that it is now illegal to ask, then look surprised and say

> Oh!  I thought the law had changed and you couldn't ask that now.  Is that not the case?

Then wait for their answer.  That should be enough of a reminder for them to back off.

Of course, just because things are illegal doesn't mean that some employers won't do it anyway.  And you'll probably not be hired by them, because you're the type to push back.  That may be the best outcome for you anyway, but you should be aware that pushing back can push you out of the running.

Comment: If you're going to mention the law itself, I would just do so directly and not feign surprise.

Answer (score 5):

Salary discussions should be put off as long as possible, so that you have a chance to show through the interview process your worth and value as a candidate.

As a job applicant, you should know through experience and industry research what to ask for, and also know the least you will accept in a negotiation.

When the time comes to negotiate salary, you should have a number or range in mind to offer when asked.

Ideally your previous salary never comes up in the discussion.

> What can I actually *do* if a recruiter asks me my salary?

You say what you would say if you were anywhere:

- "I'd rather not discuss my salary history" or
- "I'd rather talk about the budget for this position" or
- "I don't think my current salary really applies to this job"

Regardless of the law, you are under no obligation to reveal your salary history.

Rather than engage in legal discussions, simply focus on what you want your salary to be.

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out what's happening here. The company is doing something illegal which is a big red flag. Could be that they really don't care about laws, that they are incompetent or it's just an honest mistake. The latter one is a real possibility since the laws are fairly new and recruiters have been asking this question for a long time.
2. Once you understand their reasoning, decide whether you still want to work there or not or not. If no, you simply walk.
3. If yes, give them a range on the high side. "I don't want to violate the confidentiality expectations of my current employer. But given the role, the current salary landscape and my experience level I'm looking for something in the XXX range".

There are two possible reason why they ask

1. They want to get a head start on negotiations
2. They want to determine early if there is a major misalignment. If they have 100k in the budget and you are currently making $140k, it's dead on arrival and everyone saves time and effort by killing it early.

Comment: "I don't want to violate the confidentiality expectations of my current employer" this is probably a bad thing to say in this legal context, since it's illegal for a company to prohibit people from talking about their compensation in the US

Comment: @hije It's illegal to prohibit people from talking (for example to colleagues to find out if they are underpaid), but it's absolutely fine if employees respect the confidentialy of their current employer. Especially like here when it is in their own best interest.

Answer (score 0):

## Be Direct

Kindly answer:

> "I understand it is no longer legal in New York City and the state of California to ask this question.  I can explain my salary expectations, though, if you like."

There is no harm in being straightforward and will:

1. Perhaps inform them of the rule (if they do not know it) and,
2. Let them know you are 'on top of things.'

If this causes distaste to them, you might weigh that against your desire to join the organization.

*Aside advice: it's always good to know when the law came in effect and why, just in case they're generally interestest in it, so that you can gently explain it to them and they'll understand that it's not only why you can't answer the question, but that there's a good reason for the law.*

Answer (score 0):

In New York City, at least, the prohibition is on Employers, not recruiters. If the recruiter works for the company, then that is the same as the company. You can deflect that - my salary expectation is ... or confront it - "Since it is no longer legal in New York to require salary information, I'd rather discuss my expectations which are ..."

However, if the recruiter is independent, they may be using the information for your advantage. It is generally a bad idea (whatever the state of the law is) to disclose your salary, but for a recruiter, you can look at [Nick Corcodilos' advice](https://www.asktheheadhunter.com/10373/recruiters-salary):

> Here are my two rules about salary disclosure:
>
> If it’s an employer asking — the hiring manager, the HR manager, the
> HR recruiter, or the company’s online application form — do not
> disclose your salary, ever. If it’s a headhunter or third party
> recruiter, disclose your salary only if:
>
> (a) The headhunter agrees not
> to disclose it to the employer without your express permission. No exceptions.
>
> (b) The headhunter explains how she’s going to use the information for your benefit — and the reason had better be good.
>
> If the headhunter can’t pass tests (a) and (b), don’t tell.